# Reinstall Sound Preferences

Tags: 10.10, sound, volume-control

I am running 10.10 and it has been a nightmare getting my X-fi soundcard to work with it.  But I finally have sound coming out of 1 speaker.  Anyway, somehow during the whole ordeal of trying to get the sound to work I removed **Sound Preferences**  *<sup>(System ➜ Preferences ➜ Sound)</sup>* where you can change the sound from mono to surround.  Can anyone point me in the direction of how to get this back?  Or a good replacement app would do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sound Preferences* (`gnome-volume-control`) is part of the package `gnome-media`. You can install it using Synaptic Package Manager or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-media
```

Comment: When clicking on the link I get a message that says it is already installed. However, it still doesn't show up under my menu.  I checked under the Main Menu app to make sure it wasn't disabled.

Comment: @schwiz Have you tried running `gnome-volume-control` from the terminal?

Comment: Ahh, this is not the app I am looking for.  I am talking about the one where you can test individual speakers and toggle mono/stereo/surround

Comment: @schwiz Are you talking about `pavucontrol`?

Comment: yes that is the one!  However when I type this into the terminal I get a error that says `Connection failed: Connection refused` and it exits

Comment: @schwiz looks like an issue with pulseaudio. That should probably be a separate question for here and/or ubuntu forums.